# how to run SVCUtil of WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0

I am new to `WCF` but I am trying to download `metadate` of some service.

I am using `svcUtil` application found here on my computer `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin` When I click on the file to open command line tool. It runs and scroll some lines of commands but after that the `svcUtil` closes down.

Anyone came across this before. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svcUtil is a command line, so you need to open a command prompt in order to execute it.

Open the **Developer Command Prompt** and execute svcUtil passing you WCF address, like this:

```
svcutil http://yourdns/service.svc
```

or

```
svcutil /dconly http://yourdns/service.svc
```

Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: do u know any running wcf service that I can download metadata of?

Comment: Yes, it will create a proxy class that you can use to consume the service.

Comment: when I ran svcutil it created 3 files one asd and two r similar tempuri.org. what I do with those files?

Comment: when I use svcutil it only generate .cs classes and a configuration file. which option did you use to when running svcutil?